# How to communicate between Air Action Script application and Node.js server

Tags: actionscript-3, node.js, air

can someone please suggest way to communicate between Air(Action script) App and node.js server?

e.g.

1. Communication between PHP and Flash(Action Script) application using AMFPHP
2. BlazeDS for Java+Adobe Flex and Adobe Integrated Runtime (AIR)

Please send me your suggestions, any tutorial, or PoC sample code

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample I wrote for a blog. I think the code itself pretty much explains itself.

---

Client Side AS3 Code :

```
var urlString:String = "http://localhost:1337/"; 

function Submit():void
{
    var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    requestVars.Username = "guest";

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    request.url = urlString;
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    request.data = requestVars;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleteHandler);

    try { loader.load(request); }

    catch (error:Error) { // Handle Immediate Errors }
}

function loaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void
{
    trace(e.target.data); // Response Text
}
```

Brief about the code snippet:

- We fill in the request data by instantiating a URLVariables class as
  **requestVars**.
- We fill in the url & method by instantiating URLRequest class as **request**.
- We attach an load complete event Handler to handle the response.
- Wrapping up for catching errors, we call the load method.
- URL is set to Localhost port 1337 where the nodeJS would be hosted.
- The variable set is a test field UserName which is checked for in the server script.

---

Server Side NodeJS Code :

```
var http = require('http'), url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

  var urlObj = url.parse(req.url, true);

  if(urlObj.query["Username"] == "guest") res.end("True");    

  else res.end("False");    

}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Brief about the code snippet:

- The code listens at port 1337 in the localhost server where it is hosted.
- The query string is unwrapped to get the UserName variable & tested.
- Server Responds with **true** since the value equates to **guest**.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. is there any third party library like AMFPHP or BlazeDS.